# How to increment value and use it in sc_placeholder

Tags: sxa, scriban

Is it possible in Scriban to use the value from the variable, and then increment it and then use that value inside the `sc_placeholder`

If it is not possible using the basic default Scriban, maybe someone knows some extension that I can use with this.

This is what I mean by this:

```
{{- index = 0 -}}
{{if i_item.has_children}}
{{for i_child in i_item.children}}
<div class="section anchor-header" id="{{i_child.Anchor.raw}}">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2 class="anchor-header-title">
                {{i_child.Name}}
            </h2>
            <button type="button" class="anchor-header-button anchor-link">
                <svg class="icon icon-arrow" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use>
                </svg>
                TOP
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{{index++}}
{{sc_placeholder 'section-{{index}}' }}
{{end}}

{{end}}
```

With this code I am getting an error: `Error while parsing unary expression: Expecting <expression> instead of "CodeExit" in: <operator> <expression>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this and not managed to get the `++` increment variable to work, but a simple `index = index + 1` does work. Change your template to this:

```
{{- index = 0 -}}
{{~ if i_item.has_children ~}}
{{~ for i_child in i_item.children ~}}
<div class="section anchor-header" id="{{i_child.Anchor.raw}}">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h2 class="anchor-header-title">
                {{i_child.Name}}
            </h2>
            <button type="button" class="anchor-header-button anchor-link">
                <svg class="icon icon-arrow" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="#icon-arrow"></use>
                </svg>
                TOP
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{{index = index + 1}}
{{sc_placeholder 'section-' + index}}
{{~ end ~}}
{{~ end ~}}
```

You'll notice too that I've added whitespace control around your loop and if statement, it helps generate cleaner markup in the rendered version.

Here is a .netfiddle to prove the template works https://dotnetfiddle.net/B9vgj4

### Update

It looks like the `++` operator was added in a newer version of Scriban - not sure which version, but if you try the latest (5.4.1 at the time of writing) - your original code works fine. So looks like the version with SXA does not support that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem I am still having is that I get this placeholder section-{{index}} instead of section-1, section-2 and etc

Comment: Try using string concatenation instead of an interpolated string. I have updated the answer to reflect.